# How to process A direct send message to a thread of process B?

Tags: process, pthreads, message

Now, there are a scene: 
Process A get a thread ID , that in the process B thread pool. Now, process A want to direct send a message to process B.
it can be implement?
if yes. how to do that?

Comment: There are lot of choices for IPC to choose from. Very generic list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication. Based on the question it is difficult to see what is exactly the problem you are seeking solution for. Of course to use IPC (or inter-thread communication, no essential difference), you need to be prepared to both send and receive the communication. Maybe you could clarify your question with more details what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system? For windows one way to communicate between processes is to use [shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

Comment: linux OS. normal, linux IPC can solve differ process communication. but  i'am not sure the tradational IPC , that can one process send to message to other thread .